# Recent Windows Update causing Admin issues in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, group-policy

After a recent Windows Update in December 2014 or January 2015, I now have to run a lot of programs as Administrator in order to avoid access/security errors.  I'm not sure why, as I'm a local administrator on my machine.  I am running Windows7 x64.

For instance, if I run a Command Prompt without running-as Administrator, and try using "net start" or "net stop" to modify a service, I will get various errors, such as "System error 5 has occurred" or "Access is denied".  However, if I open up my Services window, I am able to start and stop the same services without issue.  I had always been able to start/stop services from Command Prompt until after a recent reboot.  So, either a Group Policy or a Windows Update is at play here.

Comment: check the UAC slider position.

Comment: Thanks, but then what?  Slide it all the way down?

Comment: move the slider down. This is what you have done before, other wise you would never be able to run command with admin rights without running a cmd explicitly with admin rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issues turned out to be caused by a new Group Policy at work.  Once the NT Admins pushed a newer policy to correct this, the issue went away for me and other coworkers.  However, the fix suggested by @magicandre1981 also worked for others before the updated GP got pushed out, so people should try that if they stumble upon this question.

Comment: do you know which GP setting was deployed?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I do not; I'm not an admin.